# Ant use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator

Tags: java, android, ant

I am sure this is pretty easy qoestion, but I am stuck with building Android app using Ant from commandline. 
I have got this message: `(use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)`. What do I add to buildfile to make it compile using Java 1.7?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Solved it if anyone else is stuck on this one. 
I had to change `<import file="${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/build.xml"/>` file.
There are properties 
`<property name="java.target" value="1.5" /> <property name="java.source" value="1.5" />` and the values should be changed to 1.7

Answer (score 26):

You need to set `java.source` and `java.target`. Either via `-D`:

```
ant release -Djava.source=7 -Djava.target=7
```

Or put it in `ant.properties` in your project:

```
# ant.properies contents:
java.source=7
java.target=7
```

Comment: YES! edit ant.properties to get rid of this nightmare of a timethief bug. Other advices in this thread did not work here. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Heisenberg's solution is correct (kudos and +1...) but not clean: you don't have to change the master `build.xml` file (*bad!*), what you need is to add the lines he suggested:

```
<property name="java.target" value="1.7" />
<property name="java.source" value="1.7" />
```

right before the line

```
<import file="${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/build.xml" />
```

in the **local** `build.xml` file, and the default options will be overridden.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Did not help for my Android project in Netbeans on Win 8.1 (I tried to restart machine). However, when I follow rzymek advice and change ant.properties, then everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, I changed my `ant.properties` as follows:

```
java.target=1.7
java.source=1.7
```

Making changes in build.xml before the above suggested line didn't work for me for some reason.